# Mock capacitor plugin ionic react with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm trying to mock a capacitor plugin with ionic react :

```
import { ICreateAccountAction } from "../../framework/auth/interfaces/ICreateAccountAction";
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import oauthCreateAccountConfig from "../../config/azure/oauth_register.json"
import { CreateAccountResult } from "../../framework/auth/result/CreateAccountResult";
import { AuthError } from "../../framework/auth/exceptions/AuthError";


export class CreateAccount implements ICreateAccountAction {
    async execute() {
        try {
            const response = await Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate(oauthCreateAccountConfig)
            let accessToken = response["access_token"];
            let refreshToken = response["refresh_token"];

            return new CreateAccountResult(accessToken, refreshToken) 
        } catch (error) {
            throw new AuthError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to mock `import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';`

I tried :

```
describe("CreateAccount", () => {

    describe("#execute", () => {
        test("return `CreateAccountResult`", async () => {

            jest.mock('@capacitor/core', () => ({ Plugins: () => { return "" } }))
            const uat = new CreateAccount()

            const result = await uat.execute()

            expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(CreateAccountResult)
        })

    })
})
```

**__ mocks __ folder**

I tried with __ mocks __ folder too (`__mocks__/@capacitor/core.ts`)

`export const Plugins = {};`

But I still get

`OAuth2Client does not have web implementation.`

Meaning that the mock did not worked

Tried with too :

```
export const Plugins = {
    OAuth2Client: () => jest.fn()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved from `__mocks__`folder from root to `src`folder, and it worked.